# How to add classes and stylesheets to HTML in python?

Tags: python, html, api, discord.py

I am scraping data from API and inputting them into a html file using html_file.write method. I want to center the text and add borders and fonts etc.. but when I am adding for example .content class to <style> and writing  I got syntax error on container and a bunch of other stuff while using bootstrap.. How can I input them without syntax errors?

```
html_content=f"<html><head><meta http-equiv=\"content-type\" content=\"text/html; charset=UTF-8\"/>"+"""
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
     <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
     <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Questrial&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    
     
     <style>
     .content {
        width: 50%;
         margin: auto;
       background: white;
        padding: 10px;
      }

    
      
     img{
     max-width: 100%;
      }
     body {background-color: LightGray;}
     h1   {color: red;}
     h2   {color: red;} 
         
     </style>
      """+f"</head><body><div class="container"><h1><h1><font size='6'><strong>{Q}</strong></font></h1><p>{content2modified}</p><hr><h1><font size='6'><strong>{A}</strong></font></h1><p>{contentmodified}</p> </body></div> </html>"
     with open("index.html","w",encoding='utf-8') as html_file:
        html_file.write(html_content)
        print("Success")
     await message.author.send(file=discord.File('index.html'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to duplicate brackets inside f-strings. '{' -> '{{' and '}' -> '}}'

Comment: nope, still getting invalid syntax on container

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out:

```
html_content=f"<html><head><meta http-equiv=\"content-type\" content=\"text/html; charset=UTF-8\"/>"+"""
      <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
       <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Questrial&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      
     

     <style>
     h1 {
        font-family: 'Questrial', sans-serif;
          }

      p {
    font-family: 'Questrial', sans-serif;
        }


      .content {
       width: 100%;
      margin: auto;
      background: white;
      padding: 10px;
        }

      
      img{
      max-width: 100%;
        }
        body {background-color: LightGray;}
     h1   {color: red;}
         
        </style>
      
        </head><body><div class="container"><div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible" role="alert">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <center><strong>Powered by Kurdi. Join our Discord server: https://discord.gg/4UNjM6Cy </strong>
        </div><div class="content"">"""+f"<h1><h1><font size='6'><strong>{Q}</strong></font></h1><p>{r5}</p><hr><h1><font size='6'><strong>{A}</strong></font></h1><p>{anshtml}</p> </body></div> </html>"
```